# Unable to start Accumulo

Tags: accumulo

I am unable to run accumulo after i upgraded the JDK to 8. I have changed the environment variables.

I am able to start hadoop with out any Issues and i can access the data node on http://localhost:50075  (I am running all on my local machine).

And this is what i am getting in the accumulo logs

Thread "gc" died Can't tell if Accumulo is initialized; can't read instance id at hdfs://localhost:9000/accumulo/instance_id.

Here is the console output from accumulo start script

```
/usr/local/accumulo-1.6.1/bin$ ./start-all.sh 
Starting monitor on localhost
WARN : Max open files on localhost is 1024, recommend 32768
Starting tablet servers .... done
Starting tablet server on localhost
WARN : Max open files on localhost is 1024, recommend 32768
2016-07-09 21:06:09,723 [fs.VolumeManagerImpl] WARN : dfs.datanode.synconclose set to false in hdfs-site.xml: data loss is possible on system reset or power loss
2016-07-09 21:06:09,726 [server.Accumulo] INFO : Attempting to talk to zookeeper
2016-07-09 21:06:09,844 [server.Accumulo] INFO : Zookeeper connected and initialized, attemping to talk to HDFS
2016-07-09 21:06:09,915 [server.Accumulo] WARN : Waiting for the NameNode to leave safemode
2016-07-09 21:06:09,915 [server.Accumulo] INFO : Backing off due to failure; current sleep period is 1.0 seconds
2016-07-09 21:06:10,917 [server.Accumulo] WARN : Waiting for the NameNode to leave safemode
2016-07-09 21:06:10,917 [server.Accumulo] INFO : Backing off due to failure; current sleep period is 2.0 seconds
2016-07-09 21:06:12,918 [server.Accumulo] WARN : Waiting for the NameNode to leave safemode
2016-07-09 21:06:12,918 [server.Accumulo] INFO : Backing off due to failure; current sleep period is 4.0 seconds
2016-07-09 21:06:16,919 [server.Accumulo] WARN : Waiting for the NameNode to leave safemode
2016-07-09 21:06:16,919 [server.Accumulo] INFO : Backing off due to failure; current sleep period is 8.0 seconds
2016-07-09 21:06:24,920 [server.Accumulo] WARN : Waiting for the NameNode to leave safemode
2016-07-09 21:06:24,921 [server.Accumulo] INFO : Backing off due to failure; current sleep period is 16.0 seconds
2016-07-09 21:06:40,923 [server.Accumulo] WARN : Waiting for the NameNode to leave safemode
2016-07-09 21:06:40,923 [server.Accumulo] INFO : Backing off due to failure; current sleep period is 32.0 seconds
2016-07-09 21:07:12,926 [server.Accumulo] WARN : Waiting for the NameNode to leave safemode
2016-07-09 21:07:12,926 [server.Accumulo] INFO : Backing off due to failure; current sleep period is 60.0 seconds
2016-07-09 21:08:12,929 [server.Accumulo] WARN : Waiting for the NameNode to leave safemode
2016-07-09 21:08:12,929 [server.Accumulo] INFO : Backing off due to failure; current sleep period is 60.0 seconds
2016-07-09 21:09:12,932 [server.Accumulo] WARN : Waiting for the NameNode to leave safemode
2016-07-09 21:09:12,932 [server.Accumulo] INFO : Backing off due to failure; current sleep period is 60.0 seconds
2016-07-09 21:10:12,935 [server.Accumulo] WARN : Waiting for the NameNode to leave safemode
2016-07-09 21:10:12,935 [server.Accumulo] INFO : Backing off due to failure; current sleep period is 60.0 seconds
2016-07-09 21:11:12,938 [server.Accumulo] WARN : Waiting for the NameNode to leave safemode
2016-07-09 21:11:12,938 [server.Accumulo] INFO : Backing off due to failure; current sleep period is 60.0 seconds



Not sure what i am doing wrong..Appreciate any help.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that the NameNode is in SafeMode. This is often because HDFS is aware that it is missing blocks to back the files that you had stored in HDFS on your local filesystem. Visit the NameNode UI at http://localhost:50070 for more reasons as to why the NameNode will not automatically leave safemode.

After you get the NameNode out of safe mode, verify that you still have the directory /accumulo in HDFS (e.g. `hdfs dfs -ls /accumulo`).

This directory (and the beneath structure) is created by running `accumulo init`. If that directory is not present, that means you deleted that HDFS directory (intentionally or not).

Make sure that you have HDFS configured to write to a directory which is not wiped on restart of your machine (e.g. avoid `/tmp`).

Comment: Thanks so much for your response elserj. After going to port 50070 now i understand what's going on. Here is the status of the name node.                      Security is off.

Safe mode is ON. Resources are low on NN. Please add or free up more resources then turn off safe mode manually. NOTE: If you turn off safe mode before adding resources, the NN will immediately return to safe mode. Use "hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave" to turn safe mode off.                       It looks like the machine it self is running on low resources!!

Comment: HDFS has a configured amount of space it will always leave available (specified by dfs.datanode.du.reserved in hdfs-site.xml). Add more disk space or clean up some non-DFS usage on your node(s).